# How to enable Verification Code emails for Customer Community users?

Tags: security, community, login

When you log in to Salesforce for the first time from a new computer (or new browser), you are asked to provide a Verification Code which is emailed (or texted) to you, as an additional security precaution.  Is it possible to enable this behavior for Customer Community users?

I did see [this question on two-factor authentication for community users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70272/two-factor-authentication-for-community-users/101414#101414), and the solution there could work, but I took the question to mean full TFA, where the user must provide a one-time code generated from a token app; I only need to use a verification code on first use from a new computer - which Salesforce already does for full licenses.  Can I enable this default functionality for my community?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Retrieve verification code by SMS, email, Temporary Verification code](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000198756&type=1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot. Based on this article seems that this is only available for full CRM license which excludes Community users: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000176035&type=1.

Answer (score -1):

There is currently no way to enable email verification for Communities users:

Please check the link:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231256&type=1&language=en_US